# Symmetry plane estimation for 3D point cloud

Tags: 3d

I have a question about finding the symmetry plane that separate the left and the right halves of a point cloud. We scanned an object, say a human face, with a 3D scanner, such as Kinect, which gives a 3D point cloud. Now we want to find the plane that segments the face into symmetrical left and right halves. I found a paper like https://hal.inria.fr/file/index/docid/331758/filename/cvpr2008CombesFinal.pdf, but could not find any code. Though I found the C++ code "CLARCS" doing this work, but it is no longer available. Thank you.

Comment: Requests for off site resources are off topic, but by removing the final sentence this is now an on topic question. Feel free to override my edit if I've changed your intent too much.